# My function that doubles my vector's size does not seem to be working

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers, malloc

The objective of my code is to create a vector of strings that is circular and is dinamically allocated with variable size. The code is not finished, but I had to stop because my function aumentar (increase) is not working, it is supposed to take the vector, double its memory size and reorganize the vector so that its beggining is in position 0. Just to clarify something, the i and the f in the struct fila are the beggining and the end of the vector. Since it is circular, I need those indexes to read it. As you can see, I put some printfs along the code to show you what is happening. Basically, although I send the vector to function aumentar, Q.i and Q.f always remain as 0 and 1, and so the program always says that the vector is full. I suspect that I am not altering Q properly. What I tried to do is to assign the pointer new to Q in function unshift, trying to change the original fila Q. So, basically, I am having problems with functions theory. Don't mind the unfreed vectors. I was going to do that later. Here is a sample input:

> unshift bla bla bla bla aaa ccc
>
> unshift aaaa bbbb ccccc
>
> exit

And here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef char string[20];
typedef struct fila {
    int i, f; //inicio e fim
    char **v; //vetor de strings 
    int mem; //espacos de memoria alocados para o vetor principal(char *)
    int n;
} fila;

fila* aumentar (fila* Q) { 
    fila* new = malloc(sizeof(fila));
    new->v = malloc(sizeof(char *) * Q->mem * 2);
    int n;
    for (n = 0; n < Q->mem - 1; n++) {
        new->v[n] = malloc(sizeof(char) *  strlen(Q->v[(Q->i + n) % Q->mem]));
        strcpy(new->v[n], Q->v[(Q->i + n) % Q->mem]);
    }
    new->i = 0;
    new->f = Q->mem - 1;
    new->mem = Q->mem * 2;
    return new;
}

void unshift (fila* Q) {
    char buffer[500];
    gets(buffer);
    if(Q->n == 0) {
        printf("O vetor esta vazio\n");
        Q->v[0] = malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(buffer)+ 1));
        strcpy(Q->v[0], buffer);
        Q->n++;
        return;
    }
    printf(" qi: %d qf:  %d  \n", Q->i, Q->f);
    if ((Q->f + 1) % Q->mem == Q->i) {
        printf("O vetor esta cheio\n");
        Q = aumentar(Q);
        printf("Eu voltei do aumentar\n");
    }
    int pos = Q->i - 1; //inserir no inicio e testar caso especial em que i = 0;
    if (pos < 0) {
        pos = pos + Q->mem;
    }
    Q->i = pos; //atualizando o valor do inicio para o novo primeiro elemento
    Q->v[pos] = malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(buffer)+ 1));
    strcpy(Q->v[pos], buffer);
    Q->n++;
}



//void print_first (char **v) {
//  int i;
//  for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
//      printf("%c", v[0][i]);
//  }   
//}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    fila Q;
    Q.v = malloc(2 * sizeof(char *)); //aloca os dois primeiros espacos de memoria do vetor principal
    Q.f = 1; //fim aponta pra posicao 1 por enquanto
    Q.i = 0; //inicio aponta pra posicao 0 por enquanto
    Q.mem = 2;
    Q.n = 0;
    char comando[20]; //comando do usuario
    while(1) {
        scanf(" %s", comando); 
        if (strcmp("unshift", comando) == 0) {
            unshift(&Q);
            //faca as operacoes de unshift
        }
        else if (strcmp("shift", comando) == 0) {
            //faca as operacoes de shift
        }
        else if (strcmp("print-first", comando) == 0) {
            //print_first(v);
        }
        else if (strcmp("push", comando) == 0) {
            //faca as operacoes de push
        }
        else if (strcmp("pop", comando) == 0) {
            //faca as operacoes de pop
        }
        else if (strcmp("print-last", comando) == 0) {
            //faca as operacoes de print-last
        }
        else if (strcmp("is-empty", comando) == 0) {
            //faca as operacoes de is-empty
        }
        else if (strcmp("exit", comando) == 0) {
            //destruir(v);
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you allocate space for v[0] pointer and then you assign to it another pointer:

```
   Q->v[0] = malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(buffer)));
            Q->v[0] = buffer;
```

And here, same thing:

```
Q->v[pos] = malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(buffer)));
    Q->v[pos] = buffer;
```

You rather should strcpy from buffer to v[0].

```
Q->v[pos] = malloc(strlen(buffer) + 1);
strcpy(v[0],buffer);
```

Buffer is local array, it created on the stack, and have automatic storage duration, which means its life span stretched from beginning to end of current function, and you assign pointer to it to variable with which you proceed in another function.

Also:
In `unshift` you increment `Q->n`, after `aumentar` it again 0. So basically n oscillate between 0 and 1 from function to function.

**Edit:**
I count some numbers, after first iteration you have Q.i=3, Q.n=1, Q.f=1, Q.mem=4, and then you compare in second iteration `((Q->f + 1) % Q->mem == Q->i)`, which is false.

Comment: 1. sizeof(char) is redundant, it is 1 by definition. 2. Strings should be null-terminated. So `Q->v[pos] = malloc(strlen(buffer)+1); strcpy(Q->v[pos], buffer)`.

Comment: @Anatoly
Hey! Thanks, I hadn't noticed that. You are right, I have to use strcpy in that situation. But just this change didn't fix the problem I mentioned, which is that Q.i and Q.f keep having the same values and maybe the vector isn't even being doubled.

Comment: I have fixed the part Anatoly pointed out in the code in this post.

Comment: new->mem->n,  didn't you forgot to copy this property from previous Q->n?

Comment: do you really need this cumbersomeness Q->v[(Q->i + n) % Q->mem] ?  If you want to copy all strings from Q to new just use counter n in range from 0 to Q->mem. Wouldn't this do the job?

Comment: Also, bear in mind `strcpy` will copy until it detects the end of the source string: use `strncpy` when you need to limit how much can be copied. Using `strcpy` is correct *here* since we allocate the correct amount of space for the destination.

Comment: @Anatoly 
I don't undestand the part where you said that n oscillates between 0 and 1 from function to function. I initalized n as 0 in main and then incremented it everytime I inserted a value in unshift. So it should actually go like 0, 1, 2, 3, ....

Comment: @Veltas `strncpy` is a very specialized function, it should almost never be used. In the vast majority of cases, one should simply allocate enough memory and use `strcpy`. If there's a fixed buffer and more characters than the buffer can hold, rather than silently losing information, print an error message and abort.

Comment: @n.m. You can (and should) check if `strncpy` ran out of space, the final destination array character will not be a null character if this happens. What to do with the info is down to the programmer. Sometimes copying into a fixed length buffer is wanted, I just mentioned it for interest.

Comment: @Kurosaki_Ichigo  after aumentar n become 0, look in to code, you are not initializing it in new

Comment: I finished my code people. It is fully functional now.